# Rails ActiveRecord has_many :through polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managements, class_name: 'Management', foreign_key: :manager_id
  has_many :primary_locations, -> { where managements:
    { manager_role: "primary" } }, through: :managements,
    source: :manageable, source_type: 'Location'
  has_many :secondary_locations, -> { where managements:
    { manager_role: "secondary" } }, through: :managements,
    source: :manageable, source_type: 'Location'
  has_many :primary_departments, -> { where managements:
    { manager_role: "primary" } }, through: :managements,
    source: :manageable, source_type: 'Department'
  has_many :secondary_departments, -> { where managements:
    { manager_role: "secondary" } }, through: :managements,
    source: :manageable, source_type: 'Department'
end
```

A user can manage multiple departments and locations and can be either the primary or secondary manager of each:

```
class Management < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :manager_id
  belongs_to :manageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managements, class_name: "Management", foreign_key: :manageable_id,
    as: :manageable
  has_many :primary_managers, -> { where management:
    { manager_role: "primary" } }, through: :managements, source: :manager
  has_many :secondary_managers, -> { where management:
    {manager_role: "secondary"} }, through: :managements, source: :manager
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managements, class_name: "Management", foreign_key: :manageable_id,
    as: :manageable
  has_many :primary_managers, -> { where management:
    { manager_role: "primary" } }, through: :managements, source: :manager
  has_many :secondary_managers, -> { where management:
    {manager_role: "secondary"} }, through: :managements, source: :manager
end
```

The following associations produce an error when I call `user.primary_departments`:

```
SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" INNER JOIN "managements" ON
  "departments"."id" = "managements"."manageable_id" WHERE
  "managements"."manager_role" = 'primary' AND "managements"."manager_id" = $1
   AND "departments"."manageable_type" = 'Department'  [["manager_id", 1]]
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column department.manageable_type does not exist
```

The `location.primary_managers` associations work. So it seems to be almost working except the polymorphic type is pointed at the wrong table. How can I specify that `manageable_type` is found on the `management` table?

Comment: You have a typo issue: always use the pluralized name in the where method: `where( managements: { manager_role: 'primary' } )` (notice the plural on managements)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have different table names that I have censored in order to simplify the question. I will edit to reflect the table names in the question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Would sure appreciate a solution. But when I make a polymorphic structure from scratch, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this to the `User` class:

```
%w(department location).each do |type|
  %w(primary secondary).each do |role|
    define_method("#{role}_managed_#{type}s") do
      klass = type.capitalize.constantize
      klass.joins("#{role}_managers".to_sym).where('manager_id = ?', id)
    end
  end
end
```

It adds 4 methods: `primary_managed_departments`, `secondary_managed_departments`, `primary_managed_locations`, and `secondary_managed_locations`. This is a workaround that suits our needs, but there may be something else I'm missing. I'm leaving this answer mostly for @janko-m because I can't put the formatted code in a comment, so feel free to answer with better solutions.